# How to choose between models with very small deltaAIC? (model averaging not an option)

Tags: model-selection, aic, phylogeny

My question is regarding selecting the best fitting model using AIC scores when the deltaAIC is very small between best models. I am running PMM's - Phylogeneticly-informed Mixed Models- using the package 'sommer'. The top three models with the lowest AIC scores are less than 1 point apart. I would normally use model averaging in this case but this can't be done with this type of model. How would I otherwise go about selecting between these models? The simplest model? Based on degrees of freedom?

Thanks for your help,

Comment: Why would you neglect the likelihood by selecting the simplest model or the model with the smallest number of degrees of freedom? Given the information provided, AIC is exactly what you should be using.

Comment: It sounds like the models you are considering are indistinguishable in practice when compared via AIC. So wouldn't it be appropriate to report the results you obtain from each of these models, since it is not possible to choose a "best" model among them?

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I'm inclined to do as Isabella says here and report the results from all models with low AIC. Richard- I am using AIC, but my question was regarding how to deal with models with extremely close AIC values.